# Terminal is not working in LDAP client

Tags: macos, ldap

I have logined in to the mac system through ldap server authentication giving uid and password. when i try to open terminal i am not able to give any commands.It is showing message [Process completed].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I my self solved this issue,Solution is as follows.
This is due to LDAP user shell attribute is not set properly.So we added a new attribute of type UserShell as /bin/sh manually in Directory Utility by loging in as that particular user. After that terminal is working as expected.